# Equivalence Relation problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $S$ be the relation on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ defined by $(a,b)S(c,d)$ if and only if $ad=bc$. Prove this is an equivalence relation on $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$.

I think I've found this to be reflexive and symmetric, but I'm stuck on transitivity. Can someone check my work so far and assist with testing transitivity?

Reflexive:
Let $(x,y)S(x,y)$. Then $xy = yx$. So $S$ is reflexive.
Symmetric:
Suppose $(a,b)S(c,d)$. Then, $ad = bc$. Therefore, $da = cb$ and $cb = da$. Therefore, $(c,d)S(a,b)$. Thus, $S$ is symmetric. 
Transitive:
Suppose $(a,b)S(b,c)$. Then $ac = bb$.

This is where I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $(x,y)S(x,y)$. Then $xy=yx$. So $S$ is reflexive.

Your logic here is backwards. The way you have it, you’re *assuming* that $(x,y)S(x,y)$, when in fact that’s what you’re supposed to be showing. What you should say is something like this:

> Let $(x,y)\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$. Then $xy=yx$, so $(x,y)S(x,y)$, Since $(x,y)$ was an arbitrary element of $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$, $S$ is reflexive.

Your argument for symmetry of $S$, on the other hand, is fine.

For transitivity you want to let $(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ be such that $(a,b)S(c,d)$ and $(c,d)S(e,f)$, and from that you want to prove that $(a,b)S(e,f)$. Your hypothesis tells you that $$ad=bc\tag{1}$$ and $$cf=de\tag{2}\;,$$ and you want to show that $af=be$. What happens if you multiply together equations $(1)$ and $(2)$; can you then use the fact that your $\Bbb N$ does not include $0$ to deduce that $af=be$?

Comment: Well if I multiply both equations I get adcf = bcde. Factoring out cd would yield af = be. I'm not sure if that is a sufficient answer though.

Comment: @blutuu: That’s exactly what you need to do. The fact that $cd\ne 0$ allows you to conclude that if $adcf=bcde$, then $af=be$, and that’s precisely what you were trying to prove.

Comment: Ok then perfect. Thanks again.

Comment: @blutuu: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're comparing the wrong things. You want to show that if $(a,b),(c,d),(e,f) \in N\times N$, and $(a,b)S(c,d)$ and $(c,d)S(e,f)$ then $(a,b)S(e,f)$.

Comment: Yeah I was confused about how to do this with ordered pairs.

Comment: When in doubt, go back to the set-theoretic definition. Your set is NxN, so you need to start with three arbitrary elements of NxN, then put the transitivity condition on them and prove that they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the usual definition for an equivalence relation, let me try to apply the alternative definition I discovered recently; see [Is this alternative definition of 'equivalence relation' well-known? useful? used?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/425174/11994)

All variables in this answer range over the non-zero natural numbers: if zero is allowed then $\;S\;$ is not an equivalence relation.

---

We're to prove that $\;S\;$ is an equivalence relation, i.e. --using the alternative definition and applying it to ordered pairs-- that for every $\;a,b,c,d\;$
$$
(a,b)S(c,d) \;\;\equiv\;\; \langle \forall x,y :: (a,b)S(x,y) \;\equiv\; (c,d)S(x,y) \rangle
$$
Expanding the definition of $\;S\;$, this is equivalent to
$$
(0)\;\;\;ad=bc \;\;\equiv\;\; \langle \forall x,y :: ay=bx \;\equiv\; cy=dx \rangle
$$
It seems reasonable to try and simplify the right hand side to the left hand side.  We calculate:
\begin{align}
& \langle \forall x,y :: ay=bx \;\equiv\; cy=dx \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"divide left hand side by $\;a\;$ and right hand side by $\;c\;$} \\
& \;\;\;\;\;\phantom{"}\text{-- this gives us a bare $\;y\;$ which we can use in the next step"} \\
& \langle \forall x,y :: y=bx/a \;\equiv\; y=dx/c \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: using rule $(1)$ below"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: bx/a = dx/c \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"divide by $\;x\;$; leave out now-superfluous $\;\forall x\;$; multiply by $\;ac\;$"} \\
& bc = da \\
\end{align}
Note how all divisions were allowed because our domain does not contain zero.

We've now proven $(0)$, which completes the proof.

---

Note that rule
$$
(1)\;\;\; \langle \forall y :: y = p \;\equiv\; y = q \rangle \;\;\equiv\;\; p = q
$$
has a very simple proof: for $\;\Rightarrow\;$ take $\;y := p\;$, and $\;\Leftarrow\;$ is just Leibniz' rule.